# What to do with damaged alignment dowels in block?

Tags: subaru, head-gasket, outback

Just took the second head off the 98 Subaru Outback I'm working on and I found one of the alignment dowels was badly crimped over the gasket for about 1/3 of its circumference. I have no idea how it got that way, but unless I do something about it, it's going to be very hard to get the new gasket on it without damaging it, and even if I do it's probably not going to seal right.

What's the best way to deal with this? Is there a decent way to remove and replace the dowel (even a damaged one like this)? Can I just dremel off the crimped part (taking care to shield the block)?

Edit: Here's a photo showing the good one (on the upper left) and the crimped one (on the upper right):

[image]

Comment: Can you not pull the dowel out and replace with a new one?

Comment: I think it's threaded in. Actually I'm not quite sure how it works, but the head bolt goes through the dowel. A quick search suggested people do crazy stuff like welding nuts onto these things to get them out...

Comment: A picture's worth a thousand words. If it is a conventional dowel then I expect you should be able to coax it out with a pair of pliers. Take a look at the replacement dowel to understand whether it is threaded or not

Comment: The part you are looking for is called a "straight pin". It should not be threaded (press fit). I found pn 804014060, but I believe it is for newer engines, like 2006+, so check with the a Subaru dealer before you order. From your description, yours absolutely will need replaced, but should be able to be pulled out by grabbing with a pair of Vice-Grips and a gentle wiggle. Use a brass drift to gently install a new one.

Comment: @Zaid: Today rain and now darkness have kept me from getting a good picture; I'll try to get one tomorrow.

Comment: @Paulster2, ok, now it's time to phrase your comment in the form of an answer to the question....

Comment: @BobCross We need a convert comment to an answer button

Comment: @Zaid: Pic added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At Bob Cross's request, I'll throw an answer out here for you. The information given is with the assumption your engine is an EJ25 series engine, which the 98 Legacy (assumed) Outback had, which is most likely the EJ25D (please correct me if not).

While many people call this a "dowel pin", Subaru calls it a **straight pin**. It should **not** be threaded (should be press fit). I found pn [804010070](http://parts.raffertysubaru.com/p/STRAIGHT-PIN-----------------------------EJ252PCS/49286943/804010070.html) which I believe is the right part number, but check with your Subaru dealer before you order. From your description, yours **absolutely will need replaced**, but *should* be able to be pulled out by grabbing with a pair of Vice-Grips and a gentle wiggle (maybe even a firm wiggle). Use a brass drift to gently install a new one. You do not want to damage the deck surface (where the head mounts to the engine) when installing the new straight pin.

Something else to look at here is whether there is damage to the head where the old straight pin may have dug into it. If damaged the head may require repair or replacement. You'd have to take it to a machinist to see which route it may need to go.

Comment: Thanks. I just got back from the Subaru dealership with a replacement part (for free, even) and the technician who helped me there basically confirmed what you said, and also that the new part can be hammered in with a block of wood. As for the head, I don't think it's damaged from the pin, but I suspect it may be a bit warped and I'm going to get it checked out and possibly machined.

Comment: @R.. Good choice to get the head checked. And he's right, wood will work just fine. Just ensure you have the completely square to the deck before you start smacking on it. I would bet it will go in pretty easily, though.

Comment: It came out easily with vise grips and some gentle turning back and forth. Got the heads machined and almost ready to put it back together. :-)

Comment: @R.. Good deal. Glad it wasn't as big of an issue as it seemed for you at first.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a conventional dowel pin then I expect you should be able to coax it out with a pair of pliers.

Comment: I think dowel may be the wrong word. It's hollow. Paulster2 suggested the right word might be "straight pin".

Comment: @R.. : I've seen people refer to them as "dowel pins"